# How do you produce a .d.ts "typings" definition file from an existing JavaScript library?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm using a lot of libraries both my own and 3rd party.  I see the "typings" directory contains some for Jquery and WinRT... but how are they created?

Answer (score 277, accepted):

There are a few options available for you depending on the library in question, how it's written, and what level of accuracy you're looking for. Let's review the options, in roughly descending order of desirability.

### Maybe It Exists Already

Always check DefinitelyTyped (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) first. This is a community repo full of literally thousands of .d.ts files and it's very likely the thing you're using is already there.
You should also check TypeSearch (https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) which is a search engine for NPM-published .d.ts files; this will have slightly more definitions than DefinitelyTyped.
A few modules are also shipping their own definitions as part of their NPM distribution, so also see if that's the case before trying to write your own.

### Maybe You Don't Need One

TypeScript now supports the `--allowJs` flag and will make more JS-based inferences in .js files. You can try including the .js file in your compilation along with the `--allowJs` setting to see if this gives you good enough type information. TypeScript will recognize things like ES5-style classes and JSDoc comments in these files, but may get tripped up if the library initializes itself in a weird way.

### Get Started With `--allowJs`

If `--allowJs` gave you decent results and you want to write a better definition file yourself, you can combine `--allowJs` with `--declaration` to see TypeScript's "best guess" at the types of the library. This will give you a decent starting point, and may be as good as a hand-authored file if the JSDoc comments are well-written and the compiler was able to find them.

### Get Started with dts-gen

If `--allowJs` didn't work, you might want to use dts-gen (https://github.com/Microsoft/dts-gen) to get a starting point. This tool uses the runtime shape of the object to accurately enumerate all available properties. On the plus side this tends to be very accurate, but the tool does not yet support scraping the JSDoc comments to populate additional types. You run this like so:

```
npm install -g dts-gen
dts-gen -m <your-module>
```

This will generate `your-module.d.ts` in the current folder.

### Hit the Snooze Button

If you just want to do it all later and go without types for a while, in TypeScript 2.0 you can now write

```
declare module "foo";
```

which will let you `import` the `"foo"` module with type `any`. If you have a global you want to deal with later, just write

```
declare const foo: any;
```

which will give you a `foo` variable.

Comment: Ouch... that's going to be a significant barrier for entry in many cases.  It would be nice to have a tool that could output at least "best guesses" based on type inference. While these might not be optimal, they could at least be tuned over time.

Comment: +1 - Further good news: `--declarations` generates both the `.js` file and the `.d.ts` file, which means you only need to run a single compile.

Comment: A collection of high-quality definitions for popular libraries can be found at https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: A 'best guess' tool will not be any better than the IntelliSense already existing in TypeScript. The benefit of the type definitions is in providing more information to the compiler than it can 'guess'.

Comment: @BorisYankov the file would only serve as a starting point, bag-of-ideas kind of thing, which the user will proceed to modify later...

Comment: @GorgiKosev I see your point. On the other hand, the idea of sitting down with the documentation and therefore basing the declaration file on "how it should be" and "what the author meant" instead of "how it is" has much to speak for it. When computers infer typing, they try to be as inclusive as possible. "This function can work perfectly well for both strings and numbers, let's allow both". People tend to be restrictive. "My nice workOnStrings function takes a string and that's that". The computer approach is good for static analysis. The human approach is good for communicating intent.

Comment: Note that https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped on github is a repository for a vast collection of type definitions for popular libraries.

Comment: If you have documented the library via JSDoc then I cannot see why an automated script couldn't use that data to generate typescript definition files. Making this stuff by hand for a large library is so much work for such a small percentage of users it makes it kinda pointless.

Comment: `--allowJs` with `--declaration` options can't be combined (tested in TypeScript 1.8 and 2.0). If I try, I get:
`error TS5053: Option 'allowJs' cannot be specified with option 'declaration'`

Comment: I'm reading the documentation about how to type what is in my case a very simple javascript file and it is ridiculously complex. I would just give up immediately.

Answer (score 71):

You can either use `tsc --declaration fileName.ts` like Ryan describes, or you can specify `declaration: true` under `compilerOptions`in your `tsconfig.json` assuming you've already had a `tsconfig.json` under your project.

Comment: This is the best answer if you are developing an Angular 2 module(s) you'd like to share.

Comment: If I try `tsc --declaration test.ts` I get the error `Cannot find name...` for the types that I'm trying to create a declaration file for :) So I need the types before I can declare them?

Comment: @Kokodoko, can you try add `declaration: true` to your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: Thanks, I just was wanting to generate *.d.ts from *.ts.

Answer (score 26):

When creating your own library, you can can create `*.d.ts` files by using the  `tsc` (TypeScript Compiler) command like so:
(assuming you're building your library to the `dist/lib` folder)

```
tsc -d --declarationDir dist/lib --declarationMap --emitDeclarationOnly
```

- `-d` (`--declaration`): generates the `*.d.ts` files
- `--declarationDir dist/lib`: Output directory for generated declaration files.
- `--declarationMap`: Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding ‘.d.ts’ file.
- `--emitDeclarationOnly`: Only emit ‘.d.ts’ declaration files. (no compiled JS)

(see the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for all command line compiler options)

Or for instance in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build:types": "tsc -d --declarationDir dist/lib --declarationMap --emitDeclarationOnly",
}
```

and then run: `yarn build:types` (or `npm run build:types`)

Comment: I still cannot figure out how to generate the `d.ts` files and be able to use interfaces. Do you have any examples?

Comment: The npm script above will generate the `*.d.ts` files and put them in the `dist/lib` folder. You do need a `tsconfig.json` file in the root of your project, but that should be there for the project to work anyway.

Comment: I am unable to use them, once exposed. I have the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742688 if you can make it work?

Comment: Thanks magikMaker. This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @magikMaker as I understand `tsconfig.json` allows you to define those options in a file, so you could have `{ "include": ["src/**/*"], "compilerOptions": { "allowJs": true, "declaration": true, "emitDeclarationOnly": true, "outDir": "dist/lib", "declarationMap": true }}` and running `tsc` on its own would do the same as you command line options.

Comment: Here's the [TypeScript docs for declaration files with TSConfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html#tsconfig)

Answer (score 18):

As Ryan says, the tsc compiler has a switch `--declaration` which generates a `.d.ts` file from a `.ts` file. Also note that (barring bugs) TypeScript is supposed to be able to compile Javascript, so you can pass existing javascript code to the tsc compiler.

Comment: seems currently passing *.js files into tsc generates an error "Error reading file "angular-resource.js": File not found". So you have to explicitly rename *.js files to *.ts to be able to use tsc. See this issue for more details - I tried using this on angularjs: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/26

Comment: from what I can tell, tsc can compile any valid JavaScript, but if it is not valid TypeScript (compile gives warnings) then the --declarations flag does not output a .d.ts file, so unless your library is written in TypeScript you still need to manually create the declarations file.

Answer (score 17):

The best way to deal with this (if a declaration file is not available on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped)) is to write declarations only for the things you use rather than the entire library. This reduces the work a lot - and additionally the compiler is there to help out by complaining about missing methods.

Comment: The documentation unfortunately is hopeless.

Answer (score 7):

as described in http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Anders-Hejlsberg-Steve-Lucco-and-Luke-Hoban-Inside-TypeScript at 00:33:52 they had built a tool to convert WebIDL and WinRT metadata into TypeScript d.ts

Answer (score 4):

To make things extremely simple for TypeScript newbies like me:

```
tsc --declaration FileName.js --allowJs
```

This command will generate a d.ts file in your current folder. You need to have TypeScript installed, but you don't need to be the project maintainer, and you don't need to have a larger compilation process set up. You can hand it any old JavaScript file and it will attempt to generate type definitions for you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some PowerShell that creates a single TypeScript definition file a library that includes multiple `*.js` files with modern JavaScript.

First, change all the extensions to `.ts`.

```
Get-ChildItem | foreach { Rename-Item $_ $_.Name.Replace(".js", ".ts") }
```

Second, use the TypeScript compiler to generate definition files. There will be a bunch of compiler errors, but we can ignore those.

```
Get-ChildItem | foreach { tsc $_.Name  }
```

Finally, combine all the `*.d.ts` files into one `index.d.ts`, removing the `import` statements and removing the `default` from each export statement.

```
Remove-Item index.d.ts; 

Get-ChildItem -Path *.d.ts -Exclude "Index.d.ts" | `
  foreach { Get-Content $_ } | `
  where { !$_.ToString().StartsWith("import") } | `
  foreach { $_.Replace("export default", "export") } | `
  foreach { Add-Content index.d.ts $_ }
```

This ends with a single, usable `index.d.ts` file that includes many of the definitions.

Comment: Second step, Get-ChildItem | foreach { tsc  **--declaration** $_.Name  } worked (added missing --declaration param)

Answer (score 2):

I would look for an existing mapping of your 3rd party JS libraries that support Script# or SharpKit. Users of these C# to .js cross compilers will have faced the problem you now face and might have published an open source program to scan your 3rd party lib and convert into skeleton C# classes. If so hack the scanner program to generate TypeScript in place of C#.

Failing that, translating a C# public interface for your 3rd party lib into TypeScript definitions might be simpler than doing the same by reading the source JavaScript.

My special interest is Sencha's ExtJS RIA framework and I know there have been projects published to generate a C# interpretation for Script# or SharpKit

Comment: FYI: I just made my first typescript definition file for Sencha/ExtJS: https://github.com/andremussche/extjsTypescript/blob/master/jsondocs/ext-4.1.1a.d.ts

Comment: hey Camel Case, I have put together a blog on using ExtJs with typescript:  http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/using-extjs-with-typescript/

Answer (score 2):

This answer shows how to do it in a stand alone function using the typescript compiler API:

```
import ts from 'typescript';
function createDTsTextsFromJsFilePaths(
  jsFileNames: string[]
): Record<string, string> {
  const options = {
    allowJs: true,
    declaration: true,
    emitDeclarationOnly: true,
  };
  // Create a Program with an in-memory emit
  const createdFiles: Record<string, string> = {};
  const host = ts.createCompilerHost(options);
  host.writeFile = (fileName: string, contents: string): void => {
    const dtsName = fileName.replace('.js', '.d.ts');
    createdFiles[dtsName] = contents;
  };
  // Prepare and emit the d.ts files
  const program = ts.createProgram(jsFileNames, options, host);
  program.emit();
  return createdFiles;
}
////////////// test code below here ///////////////////////////////////
import fs from 'fs'
const jsTest = 
`
"use strict"
function x(){
  return {
    a: 1, 
    b: ()=>'hello'
  }
}
`;
const jsPath = '/tmp/jstest.js';
fs.writeFileSync(jsPath, jsTest);
const createdFiles = createDTsTextsFromJsFilePaths([jsPath]);
for (const dtsName in createdFiles) {
  console.log('================');
  console.log(dtsName);
  console.log('----------------');
  console.log(createdFiles[dtsName]);
}
```

Execution of the test gives the result

```
================
/tmp/jstest.d.ts
----------------
declare function x(): {
    a: number;
    b: () => string;
};
```

The function is derived from [documentation in the type script compiler API guide](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/main/Using-the-Compiler-API.md#getting-the-dts-from-a-javascript-file)