# How to see the whole definitions: functions and variables from node modules in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, node-modules

Recently I researched in this site about importing an javascript node module into angular. But from there I have a big question about it.

Is it possible to see the functions, variables, interfaces (if it has) from the imported javascript package into my angular project?

For this great example I want to see all content from @adonisjs/websocket-client

// app.component.ts
import Ws from '@adonisjs/websocket-client'
const ws = Ws('ws://localhost:3333')

Using my variable ws to see all properties and functions but nothing appears.
But when it's about a javascript framework it works 100%, I mean you have all definitions.

Comment: Angular uses typescript, you will need a type definition file to be able to do that if am not wrong. Usually, .d.ts file will be there.

Comment: Do you mean, a library? or what?

Comment: @PankajH the module  '@adonisjs/websocket-client' has many index.js and I tried to "convert" it to index.ts or .d.ts file but no success, also i tried dts-generator, but no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a type definition for that javascript module to be able to do that.
Have a look at : [The repository for high quality TypeScript type definitions](http://definitelytyped.org/)

Comment: But that works in a single javascript file and the package mentioned above has some index.js

Comment: you will either have to generate them your selfs or use a library which has then in place. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301898/generating-typescript-declaration-files-from-javascript

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript