# How to work with external javascript libraries in Angular With TypeScript which donot have definitely typed files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript1.5

I have been working on a project in angular with typescript where all are ts files , I have to use JqxWidgets which is an external javascript framework  which doesn't have definitely typed files .. So how to use them ? i.e mixed typescript and javascript work together

We do get errors like 'Property 'jqxGrid' does not exists on type jquery '

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you produce a .d.ts "typings" definition file from an existing JavaScript library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript)

Comment: try adding a declare var frameworkName:any in ts files .. 
like declare var introJs:any

Comment: ya thanks  @NabeelHassan declare var $: any;  worked!