# Ionic 2 Cordova and Typescript (App Preferences plugin)

Tags: cordova, typescript, cordova-plugins, android-preferences, ionic2

I am working on Ionic 2 application with Typescript. 
For setting up preferences I wish to use the cordova plugin https://github.com/chrisekelley/AppPreferences/.

There are a few things I am strugling with. After a lot of googling there are a few things that I am not yet able to figure out.
It would be great If anyone can help.

1. Using the above Cordova Plugin with Ionic 2. 
   There are a few posts on the internet which got me to where I am currently. But most of them refer to javascript so dont help completely.
   How do I use and access the plugin methods in typescript as this is not an ionic-native plugin?
2. Secondly, I understand on IOS a plist file will be generated which can be modified from Application Settings in IOS as a means to update settings. How and where can I have a similar page/functionality on android?

Comment: One way would be, you create a .d.ts file. See how:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript 

Here another one: http://peter.grman.at/how-to-write-typescript-definition-files/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you instead use [SqlStorage](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/SqlStorage/) to persist data like preferences, as it is directly supported by ionic. If you do so, you need to install the sqlite plugin `ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage`

Comment: If using SqlStorage, as you suggested, then how would you present preferences to the user? Isn't the attraction of using something like 'cordova-plugin-app-preferences' is that you can present the options using the device's native screen.