# Create type definition from JS file

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create d.ts file from .js file. Many posts such as this are 2 years old [How do you produce a .d.ts "typings" definition file from an existing JavaScript library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript)

My questions that after 2 years is there any easier way to extract type into from .js file into .d.ts file?

After running

```
npm run typings -- install jointjs --save
```

the generated .d.ts file got many definitions missing. That's why I would like to get a joint.js file that contains all the stuff as input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a tool to convert JavaScript files to TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412164/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-javascript-files-to-typescript)

Comment: I am looking for tools to create .d.ts file, not tools to convert js into ts.

Comment: [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) is a very good resource. I've yet to see even a moderately-popular library that doesn't have a corresponding `.d.ts`. It already has [jointjs.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jointjs/jointjs.d.ts).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you produce a .d.ts "typings" definition file from an existing JavaScript library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript)

Comment: I have got jointjs.d.ts from DefinitelyTyped. But it doesn't include the ERD portion which I am looking for.  Also I referenced **How do you produce a .d.ts "typings" definition file from an existing JavaScript library?** and hope there would be some new tools coming up after several years.

Comment: You cannot "generate" a typings definition from a JS file. By definition, JS doesn't include types, so any automatic conversion would fail miserably. In this specific case what people do is manually edit the definition module to declare what kind of API it has. If the existing @types/jointjs definition is missing a portion, you need to manually write the actual definitions for it with a best guess for what each interface needs or returns. That's how those types have been maintained.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works pretty well without the need for installing any extra dependencies if you already have "typescript" (3.7 or above) installed: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#getting-the-dts-from-a-javascript-file