# Is there a way to create typescript "binding" to external javascript libraries automatically without "typings"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, angular, ionic2, aws-sdk, typescript-typings

I am trying to integrate Amazon JS SDK (aws-sdk) into my ionic2 project (typescript). Amazon has yet to provide a typescript binding, and for now they do provide instructions on how to use their js sdks.

There is an OUTDATED TypeScript binding in "definitely typed" for one library ("aws-sdk") but not even an outdated version for Amazon cognito.

So I was wondering, is there a way I could create this binding myself: Include the JS library inside my Ionic2/Angular2/TS project somehow?

Comment: Have you already checked out this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript

Comment: Looks like what I was looking for! Will check...

Comment: I don't know if that works to be honest, I'll check that too this weekend.