# How to import js-modules into TypeScript file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, webstorm

I have a Protractor project which contains such a file:

```
var FriendCard = function (card) {
    var webElement = card;
    var menuButton;
    var serialNumber;

    this.getAsWebElement = function () {
        return webElement;
    };

    this.clickMenuButton = function () {
        menuButton.click();
    };

    this.setSerialNumber = function (numberOfElements) {
        serialNumber = numberOfElements + 1;
        menuButton = element(by.xpath('.//*[@id=\'mCSB_2_container\']/li[' + serialNumber + ']/ng-include/div/div[2]/i'));
    };

    this.deleteFriend = function () {
        element(by.css('[ng-click="deleteFriend(person);"]')).click();
        element(by.css('[ng-click="confirm()"]')).click();
    }
};
module.exports = FriendCard;
```

Path to the file is `./pages/FriendCard.js`.

I have no problems with its import to another file using `require()`:

```
var FriendCard = require('./../pages/FriendCard');
```

So, I've decided to import this file to the TypeScript file just like that:

```
import {FriendCard} from './../pages/FriendCard'
```

I'm using WebStorm. It tells me that (**TS2305**) it has no exported member 'FriendCard'.

Maybe I have to configure tsconfig.json file somehow, but I still don't know how it works. Could you help me?

Comment: *"I'm using WebStorm, so it tells me, that (TS2305) it has no exported member 'FriendCard'."* Just a small note -- `TS2305` means that the warning/error is produced by actual TypeScript compiler/language service and not actual WebStorm .. as IDE does not use such numbering in their own inspections/parsers.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can import the whole module as follows:

```
import * as FriendCard from './../pages/FriendCard';
```

For more details please refer the [modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) section of Typescript official docs.

**Recent Updated Solution :** We need to tweak the **tsconfig.json** to allow JS modules import.
credits to @paulmest, @ben-winding  @crispen-gari solutions below.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for articulating "./" in front of the actual relative path.  This makes all the difference in path resolution at the compile time.

Comment: Is this up to date? I still get the same error... Could not find a declaration file for module ...

Comment: @nathan-h You probably need to modify the tsconfig file... more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56909179/872328

Answer (score 85):

I'm currently taking some legacy codebases and introducing minimal TypeScript changes to see if it helps our team. Depending on how strict you want to be with TypeScript, this may or may not be an option for you.

The most helpful way for us to get started was to extend our `tsconfig.json` file with this property:

```
// tsconfig.json excerpt:

{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "allowJs": true,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

This change lets our JS files that have JSDoc type hints get compiled. Also our IDEs (JetBrains IDEs and VS Code) can provide code-completion and Intellisense.

References:

- [TypeScript - Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options)
- [TypeScript: TSConfig Reference - Compiler Options - allowJs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs)

Comment: I've put inside **compilerOptions**  
``` lang-js
{  
  "compilerOptions": {  
    ...,  
    "allowJs": true  
  }  
  ...  
}  
```

Comment: Same use case like me but imo makes the migration possible harder because you start taking all legacy code as dependency into typescript.

Answer (score 17):

### 2021 Solution

If you're still getting this error message:

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module './myjsfile'
```

Then you might need to add the following to `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    ...
  }
}
```

This prevents typescript from trying to apply module types to the imported javascript.

Comment: I found this solved my problem if using ts-jest, on a `.ts` file which imports a `.js` file which imports a `.ts` file. A totally unavoidable situation with a clean solution.

Answer (score 15):

In your second statement

```
import {FriendCard} from './../pages/FriendCard'
```

you are telling typescript to import the FriendCard **class** from the file './pages/FriendCard'

Your FriendCard file is exporting a variable and that variable is referencing the anonymous function.

You have two options here.  If you want to do this in a typed way you can refactor your module to be typed (option 1) or you can import the anonymous function and add a d.ts file.  See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3019 for more details. about why you need to add the file.

## Option 1

Refactor the Friend card js file to be typed.

```
export class FriendCard {
webElement: any;
menuButton: any;
serialNumber: any;

constructor(card) {
    this.webElement = card;
    this.menuButton;
    this.serialNumber;
}



getAsWebElement = function () {
    return this.webElement;
};

clickMenuButton = function () {
    this.menuButton.click();
};

setSerialNumber = function (numberOfElements) {
    this.serialNumber = numberOfElements + 1;
    this.menuButton = element(by.xpath('.//*[@id=\'mCSB_2_container\']/li[' + serialNumber + ']/ng-include/div/div[2]/i'));
};

deleteFriend = function () {
    element(by.css('[ng-click="deleteFriend(person);"]')).click();
    element(by.css('[ng-click="confirm()"]')).click();
}
};
```

## Option 2

You can import the anonymous function

```
 import * as FriendCard from module("./FriendCardJs");
```

There are a few options for a d.ts file definition.  This answer seems to be the most complete: [How do you produce a .d.ts "typings" definition file from an existing JavaScript library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript)

Answer (score 9):

I tested 3 methods to do that...

Method1:

```
      const FriendCard:any = require('./../pages/FriendCard')
```

Method2:

```
      import * as FriendCard from './../pages/FriendCard';
```

Method3:

if you can find something like this in tsconfig.json:

```
      { "compilerOptions": { ..., "allowJs": true }
```

then you can write:
`import FriendCard from './../pages/FriendCard';`

Comment: thank you, method 1 solved my problem to import a js library

Answer (score 1):

The answers about adding `allowJs: true` to your `tsconfig.json` worked for me, but I also had to make sure the `includes: []` block within the `tsconfig.json` included Javascript files.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      ...
      "include": ["src/**/*.js"]
      ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

apart from adding allowJs and checkJs, like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false
  }
}
```

make sure that `strict` option is not set to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view references to JS in a TS file, you need to set `allowJs` to true. If it doesn't work, you may also need to set `maxNodeModuleJsDepth`, for example, to 3.