# Import js module to typescript file (normalizr)

Tags: typescript, normalizr

I'm trying use [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) library for my typescript project. So I have defined the following entity schema (js format)

```
//schema.js
import { Schema, Entity } from "normalizr";
export const user = new Schema.Entity("users", options = { idAttribute: "userId" });
```

and an attempt to use this in .ts file

```
//app.ts
import { user } from "./schemas";
```

leads to error:

> module ./schemas was resolved as "schemas.js" but "allowJs" parameter
>   is not set

If I set allowJs = true in tsconfig.json  then the error occurs:

> Cannot write file ".../schemas.js" because it would overwrite input
>   file

Also I used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41220676/5006880):

```
//schemas.ts
import * as normalizr from 'normalizr';
export const user = new normalizr.Schema.Entity("users");
```

But there is the error again:

> Property Schema does not exist on type 'typeof' .../normalizr/index

How can I resolve it?

Visual Studio 2017, ts v.2.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the type definitions of normalizr, the `Entity` class is inside the `schema` namespace (with lowercase s):

```
import * as normalizr from 'normalizr';
export const user = new normalizr.schema.Entity("users");
```