# NodeJS How to import JS file into TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, loopbackjs

I'm new with TypeScript. I'm currently learning NodeJS **Loopback 4** framework which use Typescript language. And my question is how to import some function, class which has been exported in JS file into my TS file. After search several way but it still doesn't work with me.
Here's example:

```
  // /src/index.ts
    import {plus} from './lib/test';

    console.log(plus(1,2));
```

---

```
// /src/lib/test.js
    export function plus(x, y) {
      return x + y;
    }
```

I also try using definition typescript like this

```
// /src/lib/test.d.ts
export declare function plus(x: number, y: number): number;
```

But still got error when import this function in index.ts file

> Error: Cannot find module './lib/test'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import js-modules into TypeScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219542/how-to-import-js-modules-into-typescript-file)

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb Sorry, I've followed that post and many post about this but it still got error when I try to import it

Comment: How about you when you `import { plus } from './lib/test.js'`? Notice the js extension at the end

Comment: It can't. It will be consider to test.ts or test.d.ts and ignore js extension

Comment: Please share your tsconfig. It might help find the problem.

Comment: I just found that I must put allowJs true in compilerOptions to make js file be compiled. By the way, thank you for your support

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the tsconfig.json doesn't have 'allowJs' enabled because it exports declarations.

Is there a reason you are not wanting this to be a typescript file? If you change test.js to test.ts, by making it a .ts should allow it to be recognised in your index file.

### UPDATE

Full chat history to get to this point can be found [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187169/discussion-between-christopher-slater-and-quoc-van-tang).
Repository used to test found [here](https://github.com/chrisslater/loopback-test)

OK so easy solution as @maaz-syed-adeeb mentions will work:

```
import { path } from './lib/test.js'
```

The reason the extension is important is because the definition file takes priority over a javascript file in a typescript environment. That is why the module import was blowing up.

To avoid specifying the `.js` extension you can also setup your directory structure like this:

```
src
|- index.ts
|- lib
  |- test.js
  |- test.d.ts
  |- index.[js|ts]
```

in `./lib/index` file export all from test:

```
//./src/lib/index.[js|ts]
export * from './test'
```

and then import all from lib:

```
// ./src/index.ts
import { path } from './lib'
// or
import { path } from './lib/test.js'
```

If you are using a blend of javascript and typescript (say you are moving over to typescript with an existing code base), you will need to update your `tsconfig.json` to include so you don't get the warnings in your IDE:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": false
  }
}
```

This is so your javascript files will be transpiled to your destination directory along with the typescript files.

Comment: thanks for your reply. My intention is to import JS function into TS, in real case that maybe in previous I have many function write with JS language and I want to reuse it in my TS Project (loopback 4).

Comment: I've recognize that when I put this { allowJs: true, declaration: false} in my tsconfig.json file then it works but maybe the test.d.ts file may not be required in this case

Comment: I have actually created a copy of loopback 4 and without the  `compilerOptions: { allowJs: true, declaration: false}` and it works with your example. So I think you can safely disregard that suggestion

Comment: So just to be clear, I am running `npmr run build` then `npm run start`

Comment: That's weird. You mean that you create a new app using lb4 app command than add a js and d.ts file like above, then import it from index.ts and it does not throw any error. For me it produce "Cannot find module './lib/test' " error

Comment: Yeah exactly that, would you like me to put the repo on github so you can compare? If the error persists, it could be more the environment than the application setup.

Comment: Yes, please put it on github then I will get and try it. Thank you in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187169/discussion-between-christopher-slater-and-quoc-van-tang).

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining