# Typescript ignore errors in particular file via config

Tags: typescript, npm, node-modules

Is it possible to **ignore** typescript errors in particular file via `tsconfig.json`? I know there is `exclude` property as described on [their website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), but this is not what I am looking for. As stated:

> If a file B.ts is referenced by another file A.ts, then B.ts cannot be
>   excluded unless the referencing file A.ts is also specified in the
>   "exclude" list.

It is quite logical that when you use a certain npm package, it will be always checked by typescript. Even if you try hard to `exclude` entire `node_modules` or just particular one. You will be unsuccessful. So if there are typescript errors in certain node modules file (because of some reason, outdated types, versions mismatch, ...), then you are stuck.

All I am looking for is an option to ignore typescript errors in particular library file which I can not edit. Something like `// @ts-nocheck`, but on `tsconfig.json` level:

```
{
  "nocheck": [
    "node_modules/redux-thunk/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

The `skipLibCheck` compiler option is not a solution. I would still like to keep checking for other libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure how you could ignore typescript errors and still keep the type information from the package - if there are compile errors, then the type information will be broken. You could always extend the offending types in the package and disable checking by using `any`, or you patch the broken types using https://github.com/ds300/patch-package/ or `yarn patch` if you are using yarn. The patch-approach will be most robust as it keeps everything typed properly.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR you cannot:

You can exclude a file from compilation (using a glob pattern) but as soon as you import a that file it will of course be included and part of your compilation.

TS will therefore check this file for errors. As the errors belong to the file and not to the import, there is no way to tell TS, import TS but drop the errors.

You therefore need to drop the typing. One possible workaround is to import the compiled [js file directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219542/how-to-import-js-modules-into-typescript-file) which will drop the typing definition (and therefore possibly related "bugs").

[Recent version of TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html#new-file-extensions) should normally let you import js files using the full explicit file name. Another hack could also be to import your dependency using `require` instead of `import`.

Last but not least, here are possible solutions:

- Perhaps the module you import has `.ts` files (while npm package should not include `.ts` files, only `.d.ts`), and perhaps you are importing one of those `.ts` file, you definitely should not.
- Your module is not bundled with it's typing, and you are importing the wrong TS definition version `@types/packageName`
- Your TS version is not up-to-date, or your module [targets another](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#version-selection-with-typesversions) TS
- In the worst case, you can still create a [local version](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/npm-install-supports-local-packages/) of the faulty npm module, fix it locally and use that one

Answer (score 0):

I there is a way around this problem. If there are a few wrong types in the package you can add a file in your project importing the variables with the wrong type and exporting it with the right type, then use typescript's [paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) mapping to use your own types instead of the package:

`node_modules/package/wrongType.js` file:

```js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.Test = exports.TestFn = void 0;
function TestFn(input) {
    if (typeof input === "string")
        return "string";
    return 2;
}
exports.TestFn = TestFn;
exports.Test = {
    a: "salam",
    b: 2,
    c: TestFn(80)
};
```

`node_modules/package/wrongType.d.ts` file:

```js
export interface TestType {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}
export declare function TestFn(input: any): number;
export declare const Test: TestType;
```

`tsconfig.json` file:

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "package/wrongType": ["src/components/rightType"]
    }
    ...
```

`src/components/rightType.ts` file:

```js
import { Test as WrongTest } from "package/wrongType";

interface TestType {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: number;
}

// @ts-ignore
export const Test: TestType = WrongTest;
```

Now everywhere that has `import { Test } from "package/wrongType"` typescript will find the correct types defined by you, and when the package is fixed you can just remove your `paths` and `rightType` file and everything will still be okay.