# Importing jsx in tsx

Tags: reactjs, tsx

I have inherited a bit of a legacy project with JSX. I am in the process of converting the JSX into TSX.

Currently while importing JSX and JS files in TSX. I get an error `Cannot find module 'config/abc_module' or its corresponding type declarations.`.

I understand the types are missing as it is a JS file. I have added JSDoc types, but nothing seems to help. What would be the best way to add types in JSX files to use them in TSX.

I have quite a few files in JS, and some I cannot even convert due to specific reasons. I have searched a lot and read quite a few articles, but can't seem to find any specific way forward. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. make a global.d.ts file in your root directory where all your code files are
2. in file write lines:

`declare module 'path/to/your/js/or/jsx'`

now these js/jsx files will resolve as modules to import in your typescript code! enjoy!

Edit: also make sure your tsconfig.json is configured to let you mix ts/js

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just change the extensions from `.js` or `.jsx` -> `.tsx`. TypeScript is supposed to be a superset of JavaScript.

Also see this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219542/how-to-import-js-modules-into-typescript-file)

Comment: By default TS is a superset of JS, but this isn't always true because some projects use strict ts, and have the build fail on errors.