Uncaught reference error HomeView is not defined
In my VueJS 3 project, the imports don't work any more:
On the top of my main.ts file, I have for example:
import "@/views/vue-home.vue";

If I run now npm run dev, there are no errors. If I change this import to say import "@/views/vue-homee.vue" (which doesn't exist) and save I get
 Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "@/views/vue-homee.vue" from "src/main.ts". Does the file exist?

My whole main.ts file looks like:
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import HomeView from '@/views/vue-home.vue';

const app = createApp(HomeView);

app.mount('#app');

However, if I open the app in the browser, the console says
Uncaugt Reference error: Home View is not defined at index.ts

I have also two configuration files:
//viteconfig.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

import path from 'node:path'

import tailwind from 'tailwindcss'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [tailwind(), autoprefixer()],
    },
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
})

and ts.config.json
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    { "path": "./tsconfig.app.json" },
    { "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
    // ...
  }
}

If I run npm run build
I get the following error
src/main.ts:5:22 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@/views/vue-home.vue'. 'C:/Users/imelf/Documents/floriloveslanguages/src/views/vue-home.vue' implicitly has an 'any' type.

5 import HomeView from '@/views/vue-home.vue';

What do I do wrong?
The file vue-home is indeed only JavaScript, so I don't have any TypeScript in there. But I would acutally like to mix JavaScript vue-components with TypeScript vue-components and .js and .ts -files (because I refator a project from pure JavaScript to TypeScript and want to do it step by step)
Edit: If I transform the vue-home.vue file into typescript, the error that npm run build gives vanishes, but all the other errors persist.

You need to enable JS imports in the tsconfig first "allowJs": true: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219542/how-to-import-js-modules-into-typescript-file
