# TypeScript Error TS2307 when import node_module

Tags: typescript

First - I'm TS newbie )

I'm trying to `import` some installed module (e.g. `ws`) from `node_modules` folder but I'm getting TS error TS2307 despite the fact the module is exists.

I tried to read everything Google gives, I also defined some settings in the `tsconfig.json` but nothing works.

My folder structure is like that:

```
tsconfig.json
node_modules
-- ws
---- index.js
src
-- my.ts
```

Inside `my.ts` i have the following:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/ws/index.js" />
import {player as sdk} from 'ws';
```

And I'm getting the error for the second line when I'm `import`ing the module.

I think I'm missing something fundamental but I can't figure out what it is.

Thanks to the helpers!

Comment: Does typings exist for that module?

Comment: By `typings`, I mean type definitions. If type definitions doesn't exist, try `npm install --save @types/ws` and then see if the error is gone.

Comment: amm.. where shall i install this `@types/ws` in my project or in the module itself?

Comment: Run the command from the root of your project. It will create a `@types` directory inside `node_modules`, which will contain type definitions for `ws` inside `ws` directory, which you can verify after installing types.

Comment: got you, and if i have my own custom module (instead of `ws`), let's say `myNpmModule`, shall i create another `@types/myNpmModule` module for it?

Comment: No, when you create your own module, you will run `tsc` command to transpile​ your typescript code to plain JavaScript code, at that time typescript compiler will generate all the required type definitions for you. You just need to install your local module. If you want to install your module locally, you can first compile your module by executing `tsc` command and then `npm install ../path/to/your/module`

Comment: And if my own module is non-typescript module but regular JS code?

Comment: You can take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript) question for more information on type definitions for non-typescript modules.

Comment: ok, i'll try, thanks )