# How to generate a index.d.ts file from a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I am starting to learn Typescript and so far so good when types are available to me to download. However, I have a javascript file that doesn't have its matching typescript and I would like to create my own one but I don't know how to do it or where to start.

The JS in question comes from https://docs.pci-proxy.com/inline-payment-frames.html and it is available at this url: https://pay.sandbox.datatrans.com/upp/payment/js/datatrans-inline-1.0.0.js

Could someone help me to create a basic TypeScript file that allows me to at least call the **this.initTokenize** function? The rest of tunctions are pretty similar so I should be able to mimic same logic by myself and learn from the example.

Thanks!

Comment: Will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript

Comment: What you are looking for is to generate a TS definition file. A search on tsd would help you write or find the definition you are looking for.

Comment: You are right. I am looking for a d.ts file.

Comment: `tsc -d` http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html check param `-d`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you produce a .d.ts "typings" definition file from an existing JavaScript library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to generate a index.d.ts file from a Javascript file

Compile the JavaScript using TypeScript with options `declaration: true, allowJs: true`. You will get a new `.js` and `.d.ts` file

Alternatively use the JavaScript as is with just `allowJs: true` in your project.

Comment: Combining the `declaration` and `allowJs` flags is not allowed. Doing so results in the message `error TS5053: Option 'allowJs' cannot be specified with option 'declaration'`