use externally loaded rot.js with typescript, without bundling?
I would like to use external rot-js with typescript, without bundlers.
IE load rot-js from e.g. dist/rot.js, and compile my own ts code with TSC.
This causes conflicts both for TSC, for tsconfig.json, and for type resolution during editing.
If I specify nodenext/node moduleResolution in tsconfig, editor can happily see types, but TSC will try to generate require-imports for node, which is wrong both for the externally loaded rot-js, and for our browser context.
If I don't specify nodenext as module-resolution, I may not use
import * as ROT from "rot-js";

or
import { Display } from "rot-js"; 

Without nodeNext, I could instead do
import * as ROT from "./node_modules/rot-js/dist/rot.js";

but it doesn't appear to work/editor can't see types,
and also it emits an 'import' in the js output.
rot-js\lib actually DOES contain *.d.ts files,
and even index.d.ts. But I can't seem
to actually import declarations from them..?
Display is exported in index.d.ts,
but if I try to import it directly, I get TS2846,
which says that declaration files can only be imported with
import type.
IF I try to import Display with
import type

I get the error that values can't be resolved through
import type, so I can't do e.g.
new Display(...)
If I try to install typings for rot-js, I get a dummy package
which proudly claims, that it is not necessary because
rot-js already has everything and already has typescript source.
I also tried to use triple-slash /// reference path/types, but this doesn't seem to work either.
Maddeningly, VSCode intellisense seems to 'know' the syntax/properties for rot-js stuff, but feigns ignorance when I try to e.g. jump to a symbol. So first it says 'yeah, there is an object called Display, and it takes these arguments', but next thing it says 'a constructor for Display? I know nothing about that, who told you that?"
It feels like a labyrinth of endless combinations that invariably make something else not work.
I read through SOs suggested earlier questions on this topic, but sadly they are mostly unsatisfactorily answered variants of my question here.
Also, this is a general issue I have with typings for external modules when working with typescript tooling, so the question is broader than rot-js.
I guess I could write my own declares from scratch for rot-js, but surely the existing tooling is supposed to already work, in a way I haven't been able to figure out yet?
To sum up the problem, I 'just' want the types to be resolved/enforced, without emitting weird imports or requires. And I cannot figure out if that should come from *.d.ts files, or from actual typescript files, or..
Typings tooling with javascript is really hard to wrap your head around, unless you just close your eyes and use webpack :-/

Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript

I do not believe it is a duplicate of 12687779. This rotjs library is written in typescript, and already has type declaration files, and definitions for its types.

I eventually figured out what I did wrong - why I was stuck in a loop.
rot-js supports ES2015 modules. This means it CAN be imported with browser-native imports. I had failed to understand that.
I was stuck in older world-view, which consists of:
(1) load external js library with
<script src..>

(2) have typings referenced and DECLARED (but not imported) through e.g. index.d.ts typescript declaration files.
(3) load your own app script, which uses (1).
So whenever TSC emitted js code containing any sort of 'import bla', I got errors, and thought I had failed - since the old worldview listed above does (1) without imports.
But with native ES2015 modules, you actually DO use imports.
In particular, you no longer do the external load in (1).
Instead, your HTML file will include your script like this:
<script type="module" src="maine.js"></script>

And now, the import which TSC emits, is no longer a problem,
but instead the mechanism that actually loads your 'external' module.
In your app.ts, your typescript import might look like this:
import * as ROT from './node_modules/rot-js/lib/index.js';

and will probably be emitted in JS verbatim.
I won't cover the exact paths you might import from,
but I got a locally installed node module to load
with the path shown above.
For tsconfig.json, I got the above to work, just by specifying
the compilerOption
"target": "es2015"

That is, I did not need a tsconfig the size of the bible to make this work.
TLDR: With ES2015 modules, 'imports' in the javascript which TSC emits
are not a bug, but a feature, and the actual way your 'external' lib is loaded.
But it requires your app code to be an es2015 module itself.
This also means, I haven't really solved my original question
of how to load external libraries the old way, and get them to work
through index.d.ts files. But presumably the answer(?) is,
that with libraries like rot-js, it is not possible unless you yourself
handroll a matching index.d.ts..
Or, in some way, write the necessary type-declares.
But again, from the whole 'import type' circus with newer typescript,
it seems you can't (?) get access to e.g. constructors,
if you work through type declaration files.
So.. I still haven't solved fully understanding how it all fits together.
But at least, I figured out how to use rot.js in an elegant lightweight way,
avoiding bundler crap.
